# Core plot graph is rendered as black box when converting into pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-plot

I my application used Core Plot to render graphs, and finally there is a need to create a pdf file, there should be this graph, but when it is saved to pdf file, instead of graph I see black box.
The method I use to create a pdf:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(outputPath, CGRectZero, nil);

for(UIView *view in views) {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(view.bounds, nil);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile
    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Could someone help how to make it render properly?

As a temporary solution before creating a pdf I convert graph to image and put it on the top of it as a result pdf is rendered properly, Is there any more elegant solution?

Edited:
I applied the above advice the code looks like this:

```
        if([child isKindOfClass:[CPTGraphHostingView class]]) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, child.center.x, child.center.y);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        transform.d = -1;

        CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext,
                              child.bounds.size.width * 0.05,
                              -child.bounds.size.height * 0.75);

        CPTLayer *layer = (CPTLayer *)((CPTGraphHostingView *)child).hostedGraph;

        [layer layoutAndRenderInContext:pdfContext];
    }
```

Result on UI:
[image]

and as a result is pdf:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any fills with partially transparent colors? The alpha channel doesn't render into PDF. This is a long-standing issue with the Apple PDF frameworks.

Comment: Skotch , I create it as - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    CPTGraph* graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:_graphView.bounds];
    self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph;     But as I viewed on debug this black drawing happened with CPTXYGraph. Cause view where all graph is placed is white and graphs itself also renders properly as I understand this place is the weak and it creates this issue.

Comment: You need to use `-layoutAndRenderInContext:` to render the graph layer. This will render the graph and all of its sublayers in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks Erik for your advice, but as a result I face the same issue, I have updated the question. I am still lost with this.

Comment: If you haven't set a `fill` on the graph, do that. The default fill is `nil` which allows the background view to show through onscreen, but isn't rendered to the PDF. `graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];`

Comment: Unfortunatly it didnt help     CPTGraph* graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:_graphView.bounds];
    graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
    graph.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph;  Still the same result -> black box